# Get status code when making REST call using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, rest, http-status-codes, azure-cli

I am making a rest call using AzCli to get the backup configuration of the web apps. However there are couple of scenarios which I want to consider while making this REST call.

To get the state of the request made I am trying to get the response code for it. In the documentation Microsoft says there are two responses 200 OK and other status code are available. I am not sure how can I get status code response after making REST call.
I am not sure its possible to get the response code through AzCli , if no then please suggest alternatives.
Any help would be appreciated.

Environment

```
Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
Python 3.8.9
Installer: MSI

azure-cli 2.24.0 *

Extensions:
logic 0.1.3
```

```
url=f"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{sub_id}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{resourceName}/config/backup/list?api-version=2019-08-01"

   cliResult = self.azure_cli_v2(["rest", "--method", "post", "--url", url], log_args=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call REST API with [`--verbose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az_rest) to increase logging verbosity.

My test command to get subscription:

```
url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}?api-version=2020-01-01"
access_token = $(az account get-access-token --resource https://management.azure.com/ --query accessToken -o tsv)
headers = "Authorization=Bearer "+$access_token
az rest --method get --uri $url --headers $headers --verbose
```

[image]